# What extra power do addons/extensions have?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Compared to scripts within a page, what extra powers do addons/extensions have? They are essentially scripts, then what makes them so special? Beside being static, have buttons on the toolbar, and be able to see the locations of other tabs, what extra functionalities do they provide over scripts on a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts on a website are generally sandboxed and are limited in what they can do (for security). In contrast, extensions can live outside of the sandbox and interact more with the browser and system. For example, some extensions can manipulate browser history, browser preferences, intercept and modify pages, access your clipboard, or even execute arbitrary code on the system. Taking a look at the [Chrome extensions permissions warnings](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permission_warnings.html) can give you a pretty good idea of what Chrome extensions can do (and which most scripts can't). Also check out the [chrome.* APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) which extensions have access to.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser.

For example, in Firefox an extension can open a file on your filesystem, write arbitrary bytes to it, then run the file as an executable.  Or put another way, it can do anything Firefox itself (or more generally, any program run by the user running Firefox) can do.

Answer (score 0):

An extension is always around and theoretically works on every site (or on no site at all), while a script within a page only exists within that page. So unless you're talking about a VERY specific function/script only for a specific site, addons are more "available".

Comment: Actually, yeah, I'm wondering what extra functionalities extensions can provide.